# Facebook Comments Not allowing to post anonymous comments

Tags: comments, facebook

I have recently integrated facebook comments on my photo gallery. I am facing a problem with fb:comments. The user is not allowed to comment if he is not logged in. The user is shown the screen for anonymous comments but will not be able to post the comment. when i check the social plugins of facebook, surprisingly it is not working there too. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the Facebook developer forum for this one. Others seem to be having the same problem.
http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=226160

Comment: This actually did  not solve my problem. They are having the same problem and they don't have a solution for the same.

Comment: Right, but a solution would probably appear there first.